# How to stub Rails secret in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

Now that Rails comes with credential/secret file I can't seem to stub/override a secret with RSpec.

```
# credentials.yml.enc
my_token: 111
```

With environment variable we used to do

```
allow(ENV).to receive(:[]).with('my_token').and_return('')
```

So I was expecting to be able to apply the same logic like

```
allow(Rails.application.credentials).to receive(:my_token).and_return('')
```

But it does not override Rails secret. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: maybe check how it's implemented https://github.com/sinsoku/rails-env-credentials multi env

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be straight forward as described here https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/2099#issuecomment-472965256

```
describe 'Credentials' do
  it 'stubs credentials' do
    allow(Rails.application.credentials).to receive(:my_token).and_return('123')
    expect(Rails.application.credentials.my_token).to eq('123')
  end
end
```

Comment: Link only answers may become invalid if the link changes or something. Please include the relevant portion of code in the answer too. :)